# WPF MediaElement Natural Duration

Tags: wpf, uri, mediaelement

I have a MediaElement which I set its Source to a new Uri based on a valid String.

For example:

MediaElementName.Source = new Uri("string");

The string is a valid path, and after debugging, sometimes it sets the "MediaElementName"'s NaturalDuration, sometimes it does not..

I have been googling for at least 2 hours now with no working results..

Does anyone on here have an idea of why sometimes it would set the NaturalDuration, and sometimes it would not? I AM able to play the wav, but it has no idea on how long the wav file is (time duration).

Any help or thoughts are appreciated, thanks!!

-BTG

Answer (score 1):

I know this is way tooooo late but anyway my experience has been two variants of this problem

a) The codec (flac can be an example of this) can't find out the duration. Check and see if windows media player displays a progress bar (some flac files I had that were being generated by custom hardware had this problem) I suspect there was no "index" within the file. Also the flac format gives different results depending if it's running on a local file or over http (I suspect this is because when it can't seek within a stream it can't find the length).

b) Some codecs don't give a duration until they have rendered some material, to solve this I have a timer running which uses Player.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan and then gets the TimeSpan. This usually gets a duration within a couple seconds of the media starting to play. Checking the timespan in Player_MediaOpened doesn't reliably work.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just took a step back and instead retrieved the information using FileInfo.

```
FileInfo test = new FileInfo("myFilepath");
double size = test.Length;
```